# Logging the conditional evaluationg report for Web dependency

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-logback

How to generate the condition evaluation report which working with Spring Boot with Web dependencies. In earlier versions of Spring Boot, when I `logging` level of web to debug, I could see the condition evaluation report. But now, I am not seeing the report even after setting the log level to trace

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=trace
```

or

```
 logging.level.org.springframework.web=trace
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the logger for that report is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.

Also, make sure you set the `--debug` flag when running the app.